# How to link class with jar file in the war? (Java)

Tags: java, jar, applet, war

I have war file. It contains the following files:

```
Applet1.class
jna-3.2.3.jar
SomeClass.class
```

Applet1 class imports `com.sun.jna.*` from `jna-3.2.3.jar` and uses some functions from `SomeClass`.

When I load applet on the web page the error arise:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Pointer.
```

That is `Applet1.class` sees `SomeClass.class` but does not see `jna-3.2.3.jar`. How to fix it?

And one more question. `jna-3.2.3.jar` is loaded to the client, isn`t it?`Applet1.class`doesn`t call `jna-3.2.3.jar` from server every time? Or maybe `Applet1.class` tries to find `jna-3.2.3.jar` on the client side?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I cleaned up your formatting.

Comment: @Jim Garrison. sorry for forrmatting. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the applet needs the `jna-3.2.3.jar` using the `archive` attribute of the `applet` HTML tag. See http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#edef-APPLET and http://mindprod.com/jgloss/applet.html#APPLETTAGS for details.

Comment: @hello_amigo: If this answer solved your problem, you should "accept" it by clicking on the checkbox at the left.

Answer (score 1):

The jar file must be under WEB-INF/lib in the WAR.

Comment: I understand that it have to work. But when i move jna-3.2.3.jar to WEB-INF/lib new error is erase: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Applet1.class